# Can I start a service by env in docker container?

Tags: docker

I have some containers which use the some image, a part of them needn't to start some service when it start

So I want Dynamic start some service，avoid to change my init.sh or dockerfile,and rebuild my images again

So I get this idea, Can I start service by env when `docker run`,I try it，but it not work.

I know I can use `docker exec` to start service which i want it start,but when I have so many service to start,it's too hard using this way

So,Can I write command be environment variable to start service, like this 

`docker run -e 'service rsyslog start' -ti container_id`

or

`docker run --env-file=env-file -ti container_id`

and the env-file like this

`service rsyslog start`

How to dynamic start some service,avoid to change my dockerfile or add a images?

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea behind docker is to have one process/service per container.

But have a look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/, put `supervisord.conf` in a volume and use `docker exec ...` to start/stop services.

Answer (score 0):

As @mgansler mentioned, Docker isn't really designed to do this, at least not optimally. You might want to rethink your app environment to have some kind of smart controller which would spin up Docker containers as needed/appropriate based on config/env variables.

You could also use multiple docker-compose files to build contextual environments and generate the `docker-compose up` command dynamically, see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/

Otherwise, a more VM-centric approach may be more appropriate, like Vagrant or similar.